# Conditional inclusion in C++11 with user-defined literal?

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11 when a preprocessing directive of the form...

```
#if expr
```

...is encountered,`expr` is evaluated as a `constant-expression` as described in `16.1 [cpp.cond]`.

This is done after macro replacement on `expr`, its identifiers (and keywords) are replaced by 0, its `preprocessing-tokens` are converted to `tokens`, `defined` operator is evaluated, and so on.

My question is what happens when one of the tokens in `expr` is a `user-defined-literal`?

User defined literals are like function calls, but function calls can't occur in `expr` (I think), as a side effect of the identifier replacement.  However technically `user-defined-literals` could survive.

I suspect it is an error, but I can't quite see how to conclude that from the standard?

Perhaps the (pedantic) impact of adding user defined literals on clause 16 `[cpp]` was simply ignored?

Or am I missing something?

**Update:**

To clarify by an example:

What does this preprocess to:

```
#if 123_foo + 5.5 > 100
bar
#else
baz
#endif
```

bar or baz or is it an error?

GCC 4.7 reports:

```
test.cpp:1:5: error: user-defined literal in preprocessor expression
```

so it thinks it is an error.  Can this be justified with reference to the standard?  Or is this just "implicit"?

Comment: The preprocessor's notion of "constant expression" is quite different that that of C++, I believe. You can really only use literals and macros that expand to literals eventually... at least that's how I always understood it.

Comment: Looks like your version of g++ is missing something, not you.

Comment: I doubt it was the intent of the committee to allow this sort of thing, since the logic of preprocessing and language semantics have always been so separated.  But yeah, the Standard does seem to imply it should be handled.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think this is the first significant divergence between the C and C++ preprocessing behaviors (which does not bode well for header files using `#if __cplusplus`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In C++11 when a preprocessing directive of the form... `#if expr ...`is encountered, 
>   `expr` is evaluated as a `constant-expression` as described in `16.1 [cpp.cond]`.
>
> This is done after macro replacement on `expr`, its identifiers (and keywords) are 
>   replaced by `0`, its `preprocessing-tokens` are converted to `tokens`, 
>   `defined` operator is evaluated, and so on.
>
> My question is what happens when one of the `tokens` in `expr` is a
>   `user-defined-literal`?

The program is ill-formed.

The core of my argument is gleaned from the observation in `16.1/1` footnote `147`, that in translation phase 4 there are no `identifiers` other than macro names yet.

Argument:

According to `2.14.8 [lex.ext]/2`

> A `user-defined-literal` is treated as a call to a `literal operator`
>   or `literal operator template` `(13.5.8)`.

So here we have a remaining call to an (operator) function even after all the substitutions described in `16.1/4`. (Other attempts, for example to use a `constexpr` function, would be thwarted by the substitution of all non-macro `identifiers`by `0`.)

As this occurs in translation phase 4, there are **no** defined or even declared functions yet; an attempted lookup of the `literal-operator-id` must fail (see footnote 147 in `16.1/1` for a similar argument).

From a slightly different angle, looking at `5.19/2`we find:

> A `conditional-expression` is a `core constant expression` unless it
>   involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated subexpression
>   (3.2) [...]:
>
> - [...]
> - an invocation of a function other than a constexpr constructor for a literal class or a constexpr function;
> - an invocation of an undefined constexpr function or an undefined constexpr constructor [...];

From this, use of a `user-defined literal` in a `constant expression` requires a *defined* and *constexpr* `literal operator`, which again can't be available in translation phase 4.

gcc is right to reject this.

Answer (score 0):

> In C++11 when a preprocessing directive of the form `#ifdef expr` is encountered, `expr` is evaluated as a constant-expression as described 16.1. This is done after macro replacement on expr, its identifiers (and keywords) are replaced by 0, its preprocessing-tokens are converted to tokens, defined operator is evaluated, and so on.

No!

The argument to `#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, or `defined` is *not* evaluated. For example, suppose I never `#define` the preprocessor symbol `SYMBOL_THAT_IS_NEVER_DEFINED`. This is perfectly valid:

```
#ifdef SYMBOL_THAT_IS_NEVER_DEFINED
code
#endif
```

Expanding a symbol that symbol isn't defined is illegal. This is illegal assuming `SYMBOL_THAT_IS_NEVER_DEFINED` hasn't been defined:

```
#if SYMBOL_THAT_IS_NEVER_DEFINED
code
#endif
```

Analogous to checking whether a pointer is non-null before dereferencing it, checking whether a symbol is defined before using it is legal:

```
#if (defined SYMBOL_THAT_MIGHT_BE_DEFINED) && SYMBOL_THAT_MIGHT_BE_DEFINED
code
#endif
```

Comment: Sorry I made a typo in the question, I meant `#if expr`, not `#ifdef expr`.  I have corrected the question, please adjust your answer appropriately.

Comment: Also note that `expr` in my question represents a whole series of tokens matching a `constant-expression` - and not the single identifier `expr`.

Comment: What do you mean "No!"?  You're arguing with the Standard.  Also, the rest of your answer is wrong too.  -1

Comment: @BenVoigt: I think I confused him because I accidentally misquoted the standard by talking about `#ifdef` instead of `#if` as I intended to.

Comment: @user1131467: In `#ifdef expr`, it's evaluated as `defined (expr)`.  But there are enough other errors in this answer that the change to the question doesn't change my vote.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The question was originally written with regard to `#ifdef expr`, not `#if expr`. In which way, exactly, am I arguing with the standard with regard to `#ifdef` (or `defined`)? Read the question to which I responded, not the question as it currently stands.

Comment: @David: Everything from the word "Expanding" onward is 100% incorrect.